# Getting SelectedTabIndex from tabbed layoutgroup

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I need a way to know what tab is selected inside a tabbed layoutgroup.
This is the code of my view:

```
<dxlc:LayoutGroup View="Tabs" Width="{Binding ElementName=MainGroup, Path=ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay}" >
                    <dxlc:LayoutGroup Header="Service lines">
                        <Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                    <dxlc:LayoutGroup Header="Cargo">
                    <Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
```

I always retreive 0 when I use the property SelectedTabIndex. Any ideas?

Greets

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about this DevExpress control, but I *can* read... after looking at their documentation regarding this `LayoutGroup` control, I noticed a few things:

From the [LayoutGroup.SelectedTabIndex Property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfDockingLayoutGroup_SelectedTabIndextopic) page at DevExpress:

> To enable the tabbed interface for a LayoutGroup object, set the GroupBorderStyle property to GroupBorderStyle.Tabbed.

Did you do that, because it doesn't look like it?

I imagine that you would use this property like:

```
int index = layoutGroup.SelectedTabIndex;
```

On the same page, it also says:

> To get the selected item, use the SelectedItem property.

So, if the above property *really* doesn't work, then maybe you could try something like this:

```
var selectedTab = tabItem1;
if (layoutGroup.SelectedItem == tabItem2) selectedTab = tabItem2;
else if (layoutGroup.SelectedItem == tabItem3) selectedTab = tabItem3;
...
else if (layoutGroup.SelectedItem == tabItem10) selectedTab = tabItem10;

// do something with the selected tab item here
```

Comment: There is no property "GroupBorderStyle" available, i'm using View="Tabs" insetad. But it is weird that I always receive tabindex 0. And every layoutgroup, which is a tab under the head layoutgroup, has also SelectedTabIndex 0, just like the parent. So no idea what i'm doing wrong..

Comment: There is a documentation page for the [`LayoutGroup.GroupBorderStyle`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfDockingLayoutGroup_GroupBorderStyletopic) property, so if you *really* don't have one on your `LayoutGroup` object, then I would contact `DevExpress` instead of StackOverflow users.